# Sharepoint Online new form move bottom save button location and change text to submit

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, form, custom

I've made some edits to the new form whereby I hide several fields. Issue is, the table sections which hold those hidden items are causing a large gap between the apparent bottom of the form and the save button. I would also like to change the word save to Submit.

I've attached a picture showing what I would like to achieve. To clarify this is not in relation to the save button at the top of the form. Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add CSS to hide the entire row, sampe CSS:

```
.ms-formtable tr:nth-child(3) {
display: none;}
```